# .net core identity RoleManager exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I create new class for change id type:

```
public sealed class Role : IdentityRole<long>
{

}
```

In AppContext it looks like:

```
builder.Entity<Role>(i => {
    i.ToTable("tblRole");
    i.HasKey(x => x.Id);
});
```

But when i try to create object of class RoleManager:

```
RoleManager<Role> roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>();
```

I have this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: A parameterless constructor was not found
>   on entity type 'Role'. In order to create an instance of 'Role' EF
>   requires that a parameterless constructor be declared.

When i change type:

```
RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
```

Have this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole]'
>   has been registered.

How i can fix this problem and add useRoleManager for add role?
Cheers!

Comment: how do you call `AddIdentity`?

Comment: @NtFreX like this:
`services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext, long>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddUserStore<UserStore<User, Role, ApplicationContext, long>>()
                .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<Role, ApplicationContext, long>>(); ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a constructor and members in class Role and link to RoleManager class if there is a relationship btw them.
You can follow this tutorial and have it genereated automatically: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)